# Transferring data from excel rows to Angular HTML Table

Tags: angular, typescript

I have excel data stored in certain variables and now I need to transfer that data to the table rows.
Below is the code :

Component.ts

```
       import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
       import { Http ,RequestOptions, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
       import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
       import { Router } from '@angular/router';
       import { Service } from '../services;

  private BulkRows : any[] = [];
  formData: FormData

 constructor(private http: Http, 
          private router: Router,
          private service: Service)

        proceedUpload(){
        debugger;
        this.service.GetExcelData(this.formData).subscribe((response) => {
         if(response && response.length>0)
          {
          for(var i = 0; i< response.length; i++){


       let BulkData = response[i];
       this.addNumber = BulkData.Number;
       this.addName  =  BulkData.Name;
       this.addID    =  BulkData.Id.toString();
       this.addAddress = BulkData.Address;
       this.addPassword= BulkData.Password;

       this.someValidation1()
       this.someValidation2()

    }  
    debugger; 

    this.BulkRows.push(

      this.addNumber,
      this.addName  ,
      this.addID    ,
      this.addAddress ,
      this.addPassword

      )         
  }
  else
  {
      this.showMessage('info', 'Add Unsuccessful', 'No data found');    
  }
```

Component.html

```
     <ng-container>
        <div class="table-responsive" >
         <table class="table table-condensed   table table-bordered   table table-striped">

     <thead>
        <tr>

    <th rowspan="2" class="center bold">Number</th>
    <th rowspan="2" class="center bold">Name</th>
    <th class="center bold">ID</th>
    <th class="center bold">Address<br /> (GS03)</th>

  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <ng-container *ngFor="let row of BulkRows" >
  <tr>

    <td class="center">   
        <span>{{row.addNumber}}</span>
    </td>

    <td class="center">
        <span>{{row.addName}}</span>
    </td>

    <td class="center">
        <span>{{row.addID}}</span>
    </td> 

    <td class="center">
        <span>{{row.addAddress}}</span>
    </td>

    <td class="center">
        <span>{{row.addPassword}}</span>
    </td>
```

Here formData contains the uploaded excel which is sent to the server , proceesed and then returned here for validation.Response contains all that data, basically it has all the rows of the excel with data. The data has to be displayed on the screen.But I am not able to display it.Where am I going wrong?

Also, the reason for running a forloop is the validation that needs to be done before displaying the data on the screen.

I am not able to figure out how to retrieve all of the rows and display all of them together:-(

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is, that you push to the array outside of the for-loop.

Comment: what I think is that here I am pushing the values inside addNumber, addName... to the array BulkRows...so the array actually contains the values and not anything called addNumber. But while retrieving I call row.addNumber which is why it does not return anything. So any idea how I can retrieve those values?

Comment: @Learner.123 Yeah, you seem to be right about that.

Answer (score 0):

Move this piece of code inside the for loop.

```
this.BulkRows.push(
  this.addNumber,
  this.addName  ,
  this.addID    ,
  this.addAddress ,
  this.addPassword
```

)